# Increase SQL loop time?

Tags: sql, oracle

Back for another attempt. I'm trying to figure out the dbms_utility get time, and want to try it out in order to test the waters. In order to this properly I need the loop to take some time to finish, all my current tries has been executed in less than a second, hence just returning "0". Any tips on how to make the loop work a bit more? Dbms_lock is not available to me, so I can't let it sleep.

```
create or replace procedure my_proc
as v_start number; 
v_end number;
v_total_time number;
v_amount number;
begin
for i in 1 .. 1500 loop
v_amount := 10 * 10;
v_amount := 10 / 10;
end loop;
v_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
v_end:= dbms_utility.get_time;
v_total_time := v_end - v_start;  
dbms_output.put_line('total time ='||v_total_time);
end;
/
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `v_start` *before* the loop?

Comment: Tried that as well. No difference. SQL must be the fastest language around, everything is done in 0 seconds. Kudos

Comment: Open some cursors.  See: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0480__PL-SQL-Programming/dbmsutilitygettime.htm

Answer (score 2):

You could use a much larger loop or do more complicated work inside it, but can also use a Java stored procedure to do the sleep:

```
create or replace procedure my_sleep(p_sleep in number) as
language java name 'java.lang.Thread.sleep(long)';
/
```

This doesn't need `dbms_lock` or any additional privileges.

Then your test can be:

```
create or replace procedure my_proc as
  v_start number; 
  v_end number;
  v_total_time number;
begin
  v_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
  my_sleep(1800);
  v_end:= dbms_utility.get_time;
  v_total_time := v_end - v_start;  
  dbms_output.put_line('total time ='||v_total_time);
end;
/
```

Which gets:

```
set serveroutput on
exec my_proc;

anonymous block completed
total time =182
```

The argument to `my_sleep` is in milliseconds; `get_time` gives you the time in hundredths of a second.